# Why doesn't BGP come up when no hold-time is defined?

Tags: bgp

Why doesn't BGP come up when no hold-time is defined?
if defined, the BGP protocol comes up without any problem.

Comment: We need more details in order to answer your question.  Please provide the equipment model, OS version, and relevant configuration,

Comment: I respectfully don't agree with  you @Ron Trunk , in my opinion this should be enough to answer this theoretical question. I don't get why a default wouldn't hold-time wouldn't be enough if none is defined between two devices.

Comment: It may be how the particular vendor(s) implemented the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Check your log file for an **Unacceptable Hold Time** open error subcode from the peer.  A BGP speaker isn't required to support the default hold time.  The specification is a bit poorly-structured in this regard, but see RFC 4271 § 6.2.